# Get string from a web server's protected folder

Tags: objective-c, .htaccess, password-protection

I have a web server (not protected) and a password protected folder in that server. I always used `[NSString stringFromContentsOfUrl: encoding: error:]` method to get data from my web server. But now, I'd like to get some data from the protected folder. When I use the same method, the string I get is just an html file saying that the server couldn't identify. How can I identify myself in order to get some data from the protected folder?

My .htaccess file in the protected folder looks like this (created by a helper tool):

```
# Begin password protection #
AuthName "Password Protected"
Require valid-user
AuthUserFile "/home/users/web/b272/ipg.edfamecom/protected/.htpasswd"
AuthType basic
# End password protection #
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Url like this one:

```
http://user:password@www.example.com/folder/file
```

I do not think this is the most secure method, but it is the fastest. Work from browser. I never try from `stringFromContentsOfUrl`

Comment: Your method doesn't work on Safari, but works on Google Chrome. When I try to use that URL with `stringFromContentsOfUrl`, I get the following error: `The file couldn’t be opened because URL type (user) isn’t supported.`

Comment: Sorry my bad, forgot the `http://` in front of the URL, your method works well with `stringFromContentsOfUrl` as well

Comment: Note that this sends the password in cleartext over the wire. Probably not the best idea.

Comment: @ipmcc The system does what he wants at the time of sending. I do not know for OS X and iOS...

Comment: @ipmcc This method should be secure enough for what I'm doing but I'm interested to learn the proper way to do that.

Comment: In short, stop using `-stringFromContentsOfUrl` and start using `NSURLSession` and friends.